# Add onclick event for a button in a Leaflet popup

Tags: javascript, events, button, popup, leaflet

I'm currently trying to do add a button in a popup using Leaflet.
That works fine. I also want to add a `onclick` event on that button. But it seems to work partially. When I replace `str` with id, the parameter gets correctly sent to `load_now()`. However, when I put `str` has a parameter the `load_now()` function does not get executed.

Here is the concerning part of the code:

```
function draw(markers, category) {
//alert(category);
  var mymap = ...
  var jArray = markers;
  for(o in jArray){
    //alert(jArray[o].id);
    var trottinette = jArray[o];
    var lat = trottinette.lat;
    var lng = trottinette.lng;
    var id = trottinette.id;
    var plt = trottinette.plt;
    var chg = trottinette.chg;
    var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(mymap);
    var str = id + "x" + lat + "x" + lng + "x" + chg;
    if(category=='user'){
      marker.bindPopup("<b>id:" + id + "</b><br>plaintes: "+
        plt + "<br> niveau: " + chg + "/4 ").openPopup();
    }else if(category=='rechargeur'){
      //TODO modifier la DB
      marker.bindPopup("<b>id:" + id + "</b><br>plaintes: "+
        plt + "<br> niveau: " + chg +
        "/4 <br/><input type='submit' value='Load Now' onclick='load_now("+ id +");'/>");
    }
  }
  alert(str);
}
function load_now(str){
//this part doesn't get executed
  alert(str);
  var id = str.split("x");
  var r = confirm("Start load process for scooter " + id[0] + "?");
  if (r == true) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "load_scooter_action.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea what I did wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: try adding ' ' on the load_now, like this: onclick='load_now( ' "+ id +" ' ) , without the spacing, was only to visualize it better

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais `load_now("+ id +")` does what I want. But I want it to work with `load_now("+ str +")`

Comment: i meant to say (' " + str + " '), sorry, have you try it with ' ' on the str?

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais it still not working

Comment: what's the output of: var str = id + "x" + lat + "x" + lng + "x" + chg; ? console.log() the variable and tell me what it outputs (you can change the lat/lng for example 0.0000 if you don't want to show the cords here)

Comment: It outputs `600x50.8377x4.38259x4`

Comment: hm.. try changing the input type to button, just to take this option out

Comment: because i just try it and it worked

Comment: I did `console.log ` on the popup content and realize it was missing double quotes around `str`. I think that was your intuition when you proposed to wrap `str` with singles quotes. Thanks

Comment: yep, that felt weird but i just went with it, glad i could help you find a solution, i just didn't post and awnser because i didn't know for sure if what i said was gonna work at all, have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

There are missing double quotes around `str` as shown in the following output:

`<b>id:595</b><br>plaintes: 0<br> niveau: 4/4 <br/><input type='submit' value='Load Now' onclick='load_now(595x50.8352x4.3669x4);'/>`

Replacing the line

> `var str =  id + "x" + lat + "x" + lng + "x" + chg;`

with

> `var str = "\"" + id + "x" + lat + "x" + lng + "x" + chg +"\"";`

solves the problem.